# Execute a shortcut to a batch file in current directory

Tags: batch-file, shortcut

I have a folder A with eps-files in it. In folder A there is a shortcut to a batchfile, which is located in folder B.

The batch file contains lines which shall convert *.eps-files:

```
@ECHO OFF
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('where.exe /F epstopdf') do @set progpath=%%a
PUSHD %~dp0
for %%A in (*.eps) do %progpath% %%A
POPD
```

When I execute the shortcut in folder A, nothing happens. If I copy the *.eps files from folder A to B and execute the shortcut, the eps-files are converted in folder B.

How can I achieve, that the file is actually executed in folder A and the *.eps-files in folder A are converted in path A?

In Linux a symbolic shortcut using `ln -sf` works in the directory where the shortcut is located. Windows seems to behave differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shortcut in Windows is not a symbolic link.  Download the utility [Junction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768) from Microsoft.  It closely mimics the symbolic link in Linux.  It's quite straightforward to use.  Just type `Junction /?` at the command prompt.

You can also use the `mklink` command that is a part of the Windows OS.  Just type `mklink /?` at a command prompt.

Comment: Thx. after trying out `Junction` I found `mklink` myself. Not as intuitive as `ln -sf` but it will suffice.